# Using SCSS get hue from one color and apply it to another

Tags: colors, sass

I am trying to use a root color to create a unique shade of gray.

Here is my SCSS:

```
@function match-hue($color, $root) {
    $root-hue: hue($root);
    @return change-color($color, $hue: $root-hue );
}

$brand-color: #314398;
$brand-gray: match-hue(#777B7F, $brand-color);
```

The resulting gray color has a hue of 0 though. Here is a screenshot of the results when inspected with [Sip](http://sipapp.io/).

[image: Visual results of color function]

I have a workaround where I hardcode the desired color into an HSL format and replace the hue value with the `$root-hue` but it's not as useful as it would be if the function worked as intended.

Any ideas?